# Angularjs-Function with model as input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why isn´t it possible to use functions like

```
<a href=""  ng-click="addTag('{{tag.name}}')">{{tag.name}}</a> ?
```

If I use the model as an hyperlink it works.

```
$scope.addTag = function (tag) {

    tagListe.push(tag);
    console.log(tagListe.toString());   

}
```

That is the code inside my controller.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be this way:

```
<a href=""  ng-click="addTag(tag.name)">{{tag.name}}</a>
```

anything inside ng-click is angular.js expression, you do not need to wrap it with `{{}}`.